# What's the right way in FreeRTOS to wait on a task to delete itself?

Tags: freertos

I'm looking through the documentation and not seeing a way to pend on a task deletion.

Is such a thing possible in FreeRTOS?

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for a task to delete itself is common in application style programming, it is uncommon in FreeRTOS applications because FreeRTOS is typically used to implement dedicated systems - a device boots up, creates the resources it needs (including tasks), and then just runs until you turn it off.  Additionally, tasks themselves are normally implemented as an infinite loop that can repeat what it is doing rather than be created each time it needs to do something.....so it would be interesting to know the problem you are trying to solve rather than just one detail of an implementation you have for that problem.

To answer your question - probably the simplest way would be for the task to somehow manually signal that it is deleting itself before it does so.  If it knows the task that is waiting for it to delete itself then it can send that task a [direct to task notification](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-notifications.html).  If there were multiple tasks then perhaps setting a bit in an [event group](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Event-Groups.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The issue with having the spawned thread delete itself after signaling its spawner is you could end up with a race condition if the spawner was a higher priority.   (Signaling the spawner causes it to run, thinking the spawned thread is dead, it exits it may reuse the thread buffer & context for something else before it actually is dead.   Anyways, I was just seeing if such a mechanism existed or if I had to work within the constructs of what was there (Just getting starting with FreeRTOS after years of other RTOSes)

Comment: You could have the task to be deleted just suspend itself instead, rather than delete itself, then have the task that is waiting for it to be deleted do the actual deletion.  In other words the task doesn't delete itself, it lets the other task delete it once it says its ready to be deleted.  Also, note if a task deletes itself then the memory used to hold that task's data structures and stack are not deleted until the Idle task runs.  If a task deletes another task then the data structures and stack of the task being deleted are freed immediately.